# "Jmeter Webdriver" which version of firefox and jmeter is required?

Tags: webdriver, jmeter

For "Jmeter Webdriver" which version of fire fox and jmeter is required ? I am unable to paste URL in browser i have used WDS.browser.get("http://www.google.com"); And WDS.browser.get('http://www.google.com');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered guide](http://The%20WebDriver%20Sampler:%20Your%20Top%2010%20Questions%20Answered)

> Q. How do I Know Which Browsers are Supported?
>
> A. The WebDriver Sampler relies on underlying Selenium and HTMLUnit libraries. Therefore, browser support is dependent on 3rd-party libraries providing Selenium integration.

WebDriver Set 1.2.0 comes with Selenium libraries 2.39.0.

Looking into [Selenium Changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG)

```
v2.39.0
=======
WebDriver:
 * Update to support native events for Firefox 26.
```

So it is recommended to use Firefox 26 with the latest release of JMeter Plugins. You can download Firefox 26 from [Mozilla FTP site](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/26.0/)

For JMeter - always use the **latest** version as it contains the most recent bug fixes and improvements including performance ones. As for now it is JMeter 2.12.

Summarizing all above:

- JMeter: 2.12
- WebDriver Set of Plugins: 1.2.0
- Firefox: 26